# How to get processId from windowHandle in Java?

Tags: java, pid, window-handles

Is is feasible to get the process Id from windowHandle or even vice versa in Java?

We have the option to get the thread from the windowHandle in Java

```
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(desktopWindow.getHWND(),null);
```

but how would be relate this thread to the processId

Answer (score 0):

From [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid)

> [out, optional] lpdwProcessId
>
> Type: LPDWORD
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives the process identifier. If this parameter is not NULL, GetWindowThreadProcessId copies the identifier of the process to the variable; otherwise, it does not.

In other words, pass an `IntByReference`, and afterwards retrieve its value. For instance (error checking omitted):

```
IntByReference lpdwProcessId = new IntByReference();
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(desktopWindow.getHWND(), lpdwProcessId);
Optional<ProcessHandle> processHandle = ProcessHandle.of(lpdwProcessId.getValue());
```